# Overrunning User Process Monitoring at Unix over a period of Time

Tags: unix

I am new to Administration front. I have a requirement :
Identify the user processes (have a list of users who submits the process) which are still active and which have been submitted 3/4 days ago.

My Approach on this:

1. Have a text file with list of users.
2. Loop and find the current processes spawned by the users and store it a file.
3. Substitute a date variable with the format and grep.

However, I am stuck how to get : Submitted 3/4 days ago. With my code its equating to a day.

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f psinfo.txt
rm -f psinfo_backdated.txt

for i in `cat user.lst `;
do
    ps -ef | grep "$i" >> psinfo.txt
done
     grep `date -d'2 day ago' +%b%d` psinfo.txt > psinfo_backdated.txt
```

I really need your comments and answer on this Gurus.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to format your code properly.

Comment: I hope now the code is readable. You can also share your idea on implementing this.

Comment: Better, but not yet correct. You can read it yourself to see why not. You can also preview it in WYSIWYG style as you type your post by looking at the preview below the area where you're typing or editing your post.

Comment: Hi Ken, This is edited properly now. Pls review and advice. As I said earlier it will be helpful, if you can share some code samples for achieving this.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this!

Comment: If some can tell if we can do grep of date range from a file like Less than Apr27 format. I can make my script work.   Waiting for the guru's to respond on this.

Answer (score 0):

> If some can tell if we can do grep of date range from a file like Less
>   than Apr27 format. I can make my script work. Waiting for the guru's
>   to respond on this.

A time format like `Apr27` is not suitable for the task, also because it doesn't contain the year, which is necessary at the start of a year. Fortunately, there is a much better format for the start time of a process. Replace

```
    ps -ef | grep "$i" >> psinfo.txt
```

with

```
    ps -oetime=ELAPSED_TIME -ouser,pid,ppid,cpu,tty,time,args -u$i >>psinfo.txt
```

(you might want to drop fields you don't need from the second `-o…`). The time since start is then represented in the form

> [[*days***-**]*hours***:**]*minutes***:***seconds*

- this you can easily filter with `awk`, e. g. to get processes started 3 or more days ago:

```
awk '{ if ($1~/-/ && int($1)>2) print }' psinfo.txt >psinfo_backdated.txt
```